# How stop a aoihttp ClientSession event stream with a KeyboardInterrupt in Python 3.6?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.6, server-sent-events, aiohttp, keyboardinterrupt

I am trying to create an asynchronous function that listens to an event stream (SSE) indefinitely, until the user presses CTRL+C to stop listening or until a specific condition is met. This asynchronous function must also return a list of processed data. Returned list must be empty if cancelled by KeyboardInterrupt.

My approach was to use the asyncio event loop and handle the KeyboardInterrupt exception but the loop/task does'nt seem to be closed after function has returned?

```py
async def async_stream(ip, port):
        key_list = []
    
        url = f"http://{ip}:{port}/ilovepython/stream"

        headers = {
            "Accept": "text/event-stream"
        }

        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
                    while True:
                        if resp.status != 200:
                            print(f"Error : {resp.status} {resp.reason}")
                            return []
                        b64_data = await resp.content.readline()
                            
                        # do things with b64_data
                        # fill key_list as b64_data is being processed
                        # return when condition is met
    
        except HTTPError as http_err:
            printl(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}', logging.ERROR)
        except Exception as err:
            printl(f'Other error occurred: {err}', logging.ERROR)

def stream(ip, port):
    key_list = []
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    
    try:
        key_list = loop.run_until_complete(async_subscribe_stream(ip, port))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return []
    
    return key_list
```

The result of this code is that the session correctly listens and does things such as print the data. When CTRL+C is pressed, data is no longer printed as expected. However when this function is called again later the data is printed twice (because the loop was never stopped?).

Trying to catch a KeyboardInterrupt within async_stream() doesn't seem to work.

Closing the event loop afterwords using `finally: loop.close()` yields errors when I call the function again at a later time.

Please note that I am working with Python 3.6 so asyncio.run() is off the table.

I would love to understand why this is happening and how to fix it thanks.

Comment: You probably should look carefully at docs for the event loop https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=eventloop#asyncio-event-loop-methods.  There's a difference between `loop.stop` and `loop.close`.  `Stop` suspends the loop but keeps its resources alive, so that the loop can be re-started.  `Close` is final - the last thing the loop will ever do.  When your `except` block is entered, the loop is stopped because of the exception, but it's not closed.  Any pending Tasks still need to be canceled before loop.close is called.

Comment: Python 3.6 is long unsupported and doesn't get security updates. You should really upgrade and then use `asyncio.run()`, which should solve the issue of running twice. If you also want to be able to deal with interrupts in the async code itself, then you should look at task cancellation. When the event loop catches the interrupt signal, it cancels the task, and you can also cancel it yourself with `task.cancel()`. This results in a `CancelledError` being thrown in your function (at the `await` line).